# If the image is B&W can i make it 12mp and 300dpi in lightroom?

Tags: canon, lightroom, image-compression

Hello soo im having a problem, i shot in raw a picture for a contest, days ago i asked a question about this. However, now that I finally took the shot and it was in B&W with the camera and also edited in lightroom B&W the image when i export it and set it to 300resolution dpi and 12.0mp it comes out getting 5MB or 6mb and thats not enough for the contest since 9MB = 12 MP. I appreciate any help guys please.

Comment: You say "since 9MB = 12MP"  — where are you getting that from? This makes no sense.

Comment: i just did a research and that was what it says like 4242x2828 in and 9MB = 12mp I dont know why

Comment: Ignore that research. Please see the link above again.

Answer (score 0):

> it comes out getting 5MB or 6mb and thats not enough for the contest since 9MB = 12 MP

I think you're forgetting compression. If you saved the photo in a format like JPEG, the data will be compressed, and that could easily account for the difference in size.

Comment: soo what could i do? since this is a contest they want me to change them the picture via email with the exif and image info ofc.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Seems like you've got a photo that's the right size -- who cares how much storage space it consumes?

Comment: sooo it doesnt matter if i just exported as jpeg and then mark 300 dpi of resolution?

Comment: According to your description of the requirements from your [other question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56148/4262), the largest dimension must be no more than 1200 pixels, which is to say 4" at 300 dpi. That means that the max image size should be 1200x1200=1.4 million pixels, right? So, export your image at that size (1200x1200px), or smaller, and send it in. (Note: that's probably a lot smaller than your original image, but the judges probably don't want to receive hundreds of 10 and 20 megabyte files.)